# Customization of AddThis code not working

Tags: javascript, social-networking, addthis

I'm trying to add the [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/) widget to my page and customize it according to this page: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api

However it doesn't seem to be working.

I am trying to output a custom selection of items, with my code being:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {data_track_addressbar:true,services_compact:"facebook,twitter,google_plusone,pinterest,email"};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

As you may be able to figure out I'm just trying to display these services: `facebook,twitter,google_plusone,pinterest,email`

But the output I get is: `print,twitter,facebook,email`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter "services_compact" is used to specify the services you want to see in the compact menu when you hover over the plus button.  To specify the buttons in the order you want, try this:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
```

By default the widget tries to detect the user's preferred services, but you can override that if you like.  Here's the specific section in the Client API that described this:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#rendering-preferred-services

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Have you try this running on mobile? Does it work for you? For me doesn't work. On mobile the addthis_config.services_compact is not respected.